# How can I debug lombok val?

Tags: lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I've been using Lombok extensively for my projects. I love it and wish it were supported officially so that the maintainers did not have to use internal APIs to continue developing, but that is a topic for another time.

Every so often, I'll run into the following issue during compilation when using `val` (which I also use extensively as it saves a lot of typing):

```
Cannot use 'val' here because initializer expression does not have a representable type: Type cannot be resolved
```

The last time this happened in two spots:

- As a return value to a function that returns a `Map<UUID, List<SomeObject>>`
- As a return value to a function that returns a `List<UUID>`

I've used `val` for the latter type before, as well as for much more complex objects than the former. However, inexplicably `val` did not work here. The final solution was just to omit `val` in these spots (though it is used extensively throughout the rest of the class with no problems).

So, the question is: *how can I debug `val` (and potentially, `var`) in Lombok*? How can I debug what it goes through to generate the type, to find out whether this is a bug in Lombok (that I might try to fix), or if for some reason my code base was misbehaving?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, there is some bug with the `val` annotation processing. There is the [issue](https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/494).
Also, there is another [bug](https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/647) with `val`. There is no warning about changing the value of `val` variable. It gives error only at run time. Be careful, it is easy to do a mistake.